# Self Launch Using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, self-reference

I am new to flutter somehow and I was wondering is there a way to make my application force open itself..like self-launch? I am trying to make an accessibility application to help the disabled but I want my application to force open itself once the user unlocks his phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not possible in flutter**, as this would be a security/usability risk.

If you want to achieve this, you may want to launch the app with 3rd party script software such as [Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/) for android. However, this would require manual configuration for each device this sould work on, so probably not what you are searching for.